# ajax post only sees first param

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, post

So here is my ajax post:

```
$("#defaultMigration").click(function(){

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Svn2GitService/services/svn2git/defaultMigration",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ svnUrl : $("#svnUrl").val(),
                               gitUrl : $("#gitUrl").val(),
                               username : $("#username").val(),
                               password : $("#password").val()
            }),
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(response){
            alert("Success!" + response);
        },
        failure: function(response) {
            alert("Error! " + response);
        }
    });
});
```

When I do a `System.out.println` in my service, I see that the `svnUrl` param is the only one that receives anything. In fact, it is receiving all of the values above. i.e. svn url, git url, username and password.

Why is it behaving like this?

Comment: I think your problem is URL encoding. If `$("#svnUrl").val()` or `$("#gitUrl").val()` contains a `&` in their values, the source sent to the server will be broken at the `&` symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity, try the following. If it works, I'll explain what has happened after.

I'm using [jQuery's $.param()](http://Create%20a%20serialized%20representation%20of%20an%20array,%20a%20plain%20object,%20or%20a%20jQuery%20object%20suitable%20for%20use%20in%20a%20URL%20query%20string%20or%20Ajax%20request.) function to serialize the `data` object.

> **$.param()**
>
> Create a serialized representation of an array, a plain object, or a
>   jQuery object suitable for use in a URL query string or Ajax request.

```
var data = {
    svnUrl : $("#svnUrl").val(),
    gitUrl : $("#gitUrl").val(),
    username : $("#username").val(),
    password : $("#password").val()
}

data = $.param(data);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Svn2GitService/services/svn2git/defaultMigration",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(response){
        alert("Success!" + response);
    },
    failure: function(response) {
        alert("Error! " + response);
    }
});
```